# How change a core block label

Tags: wp-admin, block-editor

I would like to be able to change the `core/heading` block label that is shown here, what is the best way to do so?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the block title and you can use the [`blocks.registerBlockType` filter in the block editor](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/filters/block-filters/#blocks-registerblocktype) to change the block title and other settings as well.

So for example, this would change the title to "My Heading":

```js
function changeHeadingBlockTitle( settings, name ) {
    if ( name !== 'core/heading' ) {
        return settings;
    }

    return lodash.assign( {}, settings, {
        title: 'My Heading',
    } );
}

wp.hooks.addFilter(
    'blocks.registerBlockType',
    'my-plugin/foo',
    changeHeadingBlockTitle
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much